# JPA triple “@JoinTable” annotation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I need to join 3 tables :

```
doc    
--------   
id   
id_user     


user      
--------   
id   
id_firm

firm     
--------      
id
```

In SQL, it gives:

```
SELECT * FROM DOC d join USER u on d.id_user=u.id join FIRM f on f.id=u.id_firm
```

I try:

```
@JoinTable(name = "user", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName = "id") })
```

but it doesn't work (infinite loop).

Answer (score 0):

Use inverseJoinColumns

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable( name = "user",
joinColumns         = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER") },
inverseJoinColumns  = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FIRM") })
```